# transformation function using genetic programming

Tags: transformation, computational-geometry

If I have a set of points in two spaces, say set $A$ contains 50 points and set $B$ contains 50 points. I have to find a transformation function such that if I transform the points in set $A$ using this transformation function I will get the points in set $B$. How to I find this transformation function using genetic programming? What could be the fitness function in this case?

Comment: Do you know which element of $A$ must go to which element of $B$? Are you looking for a linear transformation that does "best", or can it be any sort of transformation? Without knowing which $A$ must go to which in $B$, the fitness function might be complicated.

Comment: Any element in $A$ can be mapped to any element in $B$. But all the elements in $A$ should have one corresponding element in $B$. These are the sample points which I use to construct the transformation function and then I will use this function to transform my real points to the new space. I am looking at non-linear transforms here which gives me the best transform function

Comment: You could use any fitness function. Literally, any fitness function, and the method can converge. What you need to do is design a fitness function that bears some relevance to your real-world problem.

Comment: I don't know how to quantify it. Could you please tell me, how to quantify it?